# Android WebView: How to access JS function from assets folder

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, android-webview

I'm loading a local HTML file in my WebView and executing my JS-Function like so:

```
webview.evaluateJavascript("start();", null);
```

It works as long as I have the function declared in `<script></script>` tags in the HTML file.

```html
    ...
    <body>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function start(){

    }
    </script>

    </body>
    ...
```

But now I'm first using Webpack to bundle my Javascript code into a single JS file and store this in the `assets` folder of my app and load it like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/js/bundle.js"></script>
```

The new `bundle.js` file contains the `start` function but now I can't call it, because it's not defined.

What I'm missing here?

EDIT: Ok my function is only accessible in the bundle.js. There are multiple ways to make it work, as I want:

[Define global variable with webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37656592/define-global-variable-with-webpack)

I choose the following solution to make my function accessible in the global context:

```
window.start = function() {

}
```

Comment: Do you wait for page fully loaded before script evaluation?

Comment: yes...webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {.....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59632372/how-can-i-call-a-dialog-from-a-webview?answertab=active#tab-top may help. I did'n get your exact problem